# Permutation with duplicates

Tags: matlab, mapping, permutation

I'm using MATLAB and trying to run a randomized block of different conditions for a psych experiment. I have 'levels' I want to try out, 3 times each. So I would like to basically permute three copies of the vector, all together. So far I have:

```
levels = [0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1]
permutationIndices = randperm(length(levels)*3)
```

... and then here the natural solution to me would be a mapping function that maps whatever is in levels to the corresponding location using mod 5, so for instance in permutationIndices, wherever there is a 1, 6, or 11, the number 0 would be slotted in. How can I do this (or, is there a neater way?) Thanks.

Comment: so you want 3 random permutations of the vector `levels` and join these 3 permutations in one 15x1 vector?

Answer (score 1):

```
mod(randperm(15)-1,5)+1
```

This outputs

```
5   4   5   1   3   2   1   1   4   3   3   2   4   5   2
```

or another run:

```
3   4   4   2   2   5   3   2   4   1   3   1   5   5   1
```

which you can use to get the corresponding elements from the levels vector:

```
output = levels(mod(randperm(15)-1,5)+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
%# three copies of levels
x = repmat(1:numel(levels),1,3)

%# random permuation
[~,ord] = sort(rand(size(x)));
output = x(ord)
```

For example:

```
output =
     3     2     4     2     5     4     5     2     3     1     5     3     1     1     4
```

Comment: Why not replace the `sort(rand(size(x)))` with a `randperm` call?  They should be the same, and the `randperm` makes it clear what you're doing.

Comment: @sfstewman: actually I meant to use RAND+SORT to give an alternative to RANDPERM

Comment: It took me a minute to realize what you were doing.  Does it have any advantage compared to just using `randperm`?

Comment: @sfstewman: If I'm not mistaken, this was exactly how RANDPERM was implemented in previous versions (as an M-file). My current MATLAB R2012a shows it as a MEX-file, so I wouldn't know how it is now coded. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/274560#720486) for a discussion about the drawbacks of using RAND+SORT

Comment: actually its now a built-in function, and I'm not sure if it was ever otherwise :p Maybe someone with on older version can confirm or deny this..

Comment: My version of Matlab (R2010b) has the function, but implements it as a 1-line M-file: `sort(rand(1,n))`.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

The `mod` approach is probably the simplest.  I would generate permuted indices for an array of length `nlevels * ntimes`, and then `mod` those indices to index into an array of your actual level values.

```
level_values = [0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1];
nlevels = numel(level_values);
ntimes = 3;

lv_inds = 1 + mod( randperm(ntimes*nlevels - 1), nlevels);
levels = level_values( lv_inds );
```

The odd `1 +` and `- 1` offsets are necessary to make the `mod` call work with Matlab's array indexing (which starts at 1).